# Forfiles with 7z zip ONLY last modified file

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I am trying to zip only last modified file from a folder to help my workflow with bat file

but its giving an error

```
ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.
```

Here is my complete code

```
@ECHO ON
SET "SourceDir=C:\Users\user1\Documents\Work"
SET "ZipName=testing.zip"
SET "DestDir=C:\Users\user1\Documents\Work\result"
SET "now=%date:~4%"

CD /D "%DestDir%"

FORFILES /D %now% /m *.csv /c "cmd /c 7z.exe a -aoa -tzip %ZipName% %SourceDir% "
```

I am pretty sure there is file last modified today. I assume its didn't recognise the sourcedir? Am I missing in the quote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest not using command **FORFILES**, but use instead the commands **FOR** and **DIR**.

```
@echo off
set "SourceDir=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Work"
set "ZipName=testing.zip"
set "DestDir=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Work\result"

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%SourceDir%\*" /A-D /B /O-D 2^>nul') do 7z.exe a -aoa -tzip "%DestDir%\%ZipName%" "%SourceDir%\%%I" & goto Done

:Done
```

**DIR** searches in specified source directory with wildcard pattern `*` because of `/A-D` (attribute not directory) only for files and outputs them because of `/B` (bare format) with file name only ordered by last modification date in reverse order because of `/O-D` which means newest file is output first.

**FOR** process this output by **DIR** line by line. For the first line `7z.exe` is called to compress the file into the ZIP archive file.

Then `goto :Done` is executed to exit the **FOR** loop as all other files found and output by **DIR** are of no interest.

I suggest to specify `7z.exe` with full path in the batch file.

`2^>nul` redirects the error message output by **DIR** if no file is found in source directory to device **NUL** to suppress it. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with caret character `^` to be interpreted as literal character on Windows command interpreter parses the entire **FOR** command line. The escape character `^` is already removed later on execution of **DIR** command line in a separate command process opened by **FOR** in background.

Another version processing only files with archive attribute set and clear the archive attribute for each file compressed into the ZIP archive file.

```
@echo off
set "SourceDir=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Work"
set "ZipName=testing.zip"
set "DestDir=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Work\result"

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%SourceDir%\*" /AA-D /B 2^>nul') do (
    7z.exe a -aoa -tzip "%DestDir%\%ZipName%" "%SourceDir%\%%I"
    %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -a "%SourceDir%\%%I"
)
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `attrib /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `set /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for deep explanation! Works like a charm.